# Sharepoint Online - Search for folder with special character in query

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

Consider I have a folder in a SharePoint Library within a Sub site DM. The folder's name is: `TEST CLIENT D'ORO`

This is my search query:

```
{searchboxquery} Path:"https://rooturl.sharepoint.com/sites/DM/" ContentTypeId:0x0120D520* ContentTypeId:0x0101* ContentTypeId:0x0120*
```

Search Input: `TEST CLIENT D'ORO`, returns no results.

Search Input: `TEST CLIENT D''ORO`, returns results but not the folder.

Search input: `TEST CLIENT`, returns the expected results, including the folder.

The Folder only has a Title property. In the second scenario, the returned documents consist of a field `ClientName` with value `TEST CLIENT D'ORO`, which could explain why the search returned results. But how does it explain that it did not return the folder result with the same query? How can I search with the exact title (including escape characters if required) and return the expected results?

The Expected result: every folder and document whose title (or any other field) contains `TEST CLIENT D'ORO` within subsite DM in SharePoint online with url: rooturl.

Answer (score 0):

I used the OOB refiners etc. This is my query -

```
{searchboxquery} (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) Path:{Site.URL}
```

Now, for the same set of inputs that you have, the search works properly -

[image: Search Input: <code>TEST CLIENT D'ORO</code>]

**Update**

Please refer to [Query variables in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj683123.aspx).

Please refer to [KQL reference](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference) in order to get a better idea at constructing queries.

Please refer to [Working with Result Sources](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25783.sharepoint-2013-working-with-result-sources-to-limit-search-results.aspx) in order to understand how result sources work.

**Update #2**

Use the following query with the result scope -

`{searchboxquery} (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True)`

Restricting Search results to a subsite only -

> Site > Site settings > Search > Result Sources

[image]

> Add a new Result Source . In `Query Transform` section modify the query to contain the following (i.e. your subsite url) -

[image]
Create the Result source.

> Now go back to the `Search Results` webpart. Make sure you select the result source to be the one you just created -

[image]

> And then voila! the search results are only sourced the target subsite -

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to recreate the problem. I tried your query and the result is identical to my query. However, when I am testing in the Test section of the Build your query panel in SharePoint online, I am seeing that the query is being changed a bit:

(contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) Path:"https://rooturl.sharepoint.com/sites/DM/" -ContentClass=urn:content-class:SPSPeople

Comment: Path:"abc.sharepoint.com" doesnt seem to work for me.  are you manually building the query or using the query builder?

Comment: ABC would be the name of the SharePoint. The extension of /sites/DM refers to the sub site called DM. When trying Site.URL, it does not work for me. Besides, I need to specify that this search needs to just work in the subsite and not the root collection. I am building the query in the Query text box in the Basics section of the Build your query feature. Don't forget that I am using SharePoint Online (if you are using On-Premise)

Comment: Updated the answer as per your requirement. Please refer :). Also can you update the question with your complete set of requrirements from the search query.

Comment: I have edited my question. I have also tried your update 2. The only thing it changes in my opinion is that it used the result source instead of the path that I was previously specifying within the query text. I am still not getting the expected results. I think it is somehow a problem with the quotes.

Comment: can you use the following query and lemme know? `{searchboxquery} (contentclass:STS_ListItem OR IsDocument:True) ` Keep the result scope as discussed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62140/discussion-between-swayam-siddha-and-jurgen-cuschieri).